# what is the proper way of writing the following php echo command

Tags: php, chat, echo

please somebody help me make this correct. I have no knowledge in php

```
echo bowob_api_get_code(/* BOWOB_APP_ID */, /* BOWOB_SERVER_ADDRESS */);
```

am supposed to substitute values `BOWOB_APP_ID with somevalue 67890` and `BOWOB_SERVER with http://euwest1.bowobcloud1.com/`

I did it as shown below, but i keep getting error on this line

```
echo bowob_api_get_code('67890, http://euwest1.bowobcloud1.com/ ');
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Oh, function expects two values I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it is right now, you have a single string argument, whereas you need an integer and a string.

```
echo bowob_api_get_code(67890, "http://......./");
```